# Excel VBA Replace the nth word in a string

Tags: excel, vba, string, replace, split

my problem is the following:

I have two sets of strings. The "words" are separated with "+".

String 1: `A25+F47+w41+r21+h65`

String 2: `4+7+4+4+2`

I have a textbox that identifies the word “w41” in string 1. It is the 3rd word in the string. I want to replace the 3rd word in string 2 and that would be the second “4”

What I have so far is:

I am using split function to split string 1 where there is a “+”:

```
Result=Split(String1, "+")
```

Then I use the UBound to find the position of w41 and the result is 3.

```
FindWordPosition = UBound(Result()) + 1
```

Now I want to split string 2 in the same way. But then I want to change the 3rd word in string 2 from “4” to “3” and then put it together again. The result would be:

String 2: `4+7+3+4+2`

but I cannot figure out how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an `ArrayList`.

Not sure what you want to replace the matched item with.  In the code below, it is being replaced with the sequence number, which matches what you describe, but may not be what you really want.

```
Option Explicit
Sub due()
    Const str1 As String = "A25+F47+w41+r21+h65"
    Const str2 As String = "4+7+4+4+2"
    Const strMatch As String = "w41"
    Dim AL As Object
    Dim v, w, I As Long
    
Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'put str2 into arrayList
v = Split(str2, "+")
For Each w In v
    AL.Add w
Next w

'Check str1 against matchStr to get positions and act on the item in AL at that position
v = Split(str1, "+")
For I = 0 To UBound(v)
'Note that arrayList index and "Split" array are zero-based
    If strMatch = v(I) Then
        AL.removeat I 'remove item in the same position as the position of the matched item
        AL.Insert I, I + 1 'Insert new item at that same position. Could be anything. I chose I+1 to match what you wrote in your question.
    End If
Next I

Debug.Print Join(AL.toarray, "+")
    
End Sub
```

`=> 4+7+3+4+2`

Comment: Thank you that is awesome! But why does it not work if I change the constant to a variable. 

So, I changed your code: Const str1 As String = "A25+F47+w41+r21+h65" with 

Dim str1 as string 
str1=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1

But that will not give the correct result

Comment: @Richard Should work. Add `Debug.Print` lines to check contents of the variables.

Comment: I must have written some code wrong because I re-wrote it and now it works! Thank you for the help, you made my day! :) and I hope your day will be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

### Replace With Index

- This example should get you on your feet.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Results
' For w41:
' A25+F47+w41+r21+h65
' 4+7+3+4+1
' For h65:
' A25+F47+w41+r21+h65
' 4+7+4+4+5

Sub replaceWithIndex()
   
    Const Criteria As String = "w41"
    Const str1 As String = "A25+F47+w41+r21+h65"
    Const str2 As String = "4+7+4+4+1"
    Const Delimiter As String = "+"
    
    Dim Split1() As String: Split1 = Split(str1, Delimiter)
    Dim Split2() As String: Split2 = Split(str2, Delimiter)
    
    ' Note that an array obtained with 'Split' is always zero-based, while
    ' the result of 'Application.Match' is always one-based (hence '- 1').
    
    Dim cMatch As Variant: cMatch = Application.Match(Criteria, Split1, 0)

    If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
        Split2(cMatch - 1) = cMatch
        Debug.Print "Source"
        Debug.Print str1
        Debug.Print str2
        Debug.Print "Result"
        Debug.Print Join(Split1, Delimiter)
        Debug.Print Join(Split2, Delimiter)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop the array and exit if found:

```vb
Public Sub BuildPositions()
   
    Const Criteria  As String = "w41"
    Const String1   As String = "A25+F47+w41+r21+h65"
    Const String2   As String = "4+7+4+4+2"
    Const Delimiter As String = "+"
    
    Dim Results()   As String
    Dim Positions() As String
    Dim Index       As Integer

    Results = Split(String1, Delimiter)
    Positions = Split(String2, Delimiter)
    
    For Index = LBound(Results) To UBound(Results)
        If Results(Index) = Criteria Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Index <= UBound(Results) Then
        ' Result was located.
        Positions(Index) = 1 + Index
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Results:", String1
    Debug.Print "Positions1:", String2
    Debug.Print "Positions2:", Join(Positions, Delimiter)
    
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Results:      A25+F47+w41+r21+h65
Positions1:   4+7+4+4+2
Positions2:   4+7+3+4+2
```